# SE-MJ553BT Headsets on Windows 10 Home Edition (A2DP profile issue?)

Tags: windows-10, audio, bluetooth

#### Problem.

Yesterday I bought SE-MJ553BT headsets and tried them out on my computer, they worked *almost* well, they suddenly stopped working after loging into a fullscreen application (not sure if this is related though), it was pretty late so I called it a day.

Today the headsets work again, but the sound is pretty bad, like playing from a long distance under a pillow inside a metal fish tank. I've been trying my best to make the device work properly, but after 3h of try-and-error, enable/disable device, pair/unpair device, update drivers, reboot computer and chat with customer support the device still don't work properly.

What should I do in order to make those headsets work properly?

#### Context.

It looks like the device is duplicated:

[image: The device appears twice]

- **Headsets with microphone SE-MJ553BT Hands-Free**: If this is set as default device, sound is played whith the low quality I described before.
- **Headsets SE-MJ553BT Stereo**: If this is set as default device, sound is not played, but if I have something playing the volume bar on the right side of the screenshot reacts.

Also, under "Advanced options" the only option I have is "1 channel, 16 bit, 8000 Hz" for "Headsets with microphone SE-MJ553BT Hands-Free", the dropdown box is disabled so I cannot change it:

[image]

But for "Headsets SE-MJ553BT Stereo", under "Advanced options" the one option available is "2 channel, 16 bit, 44100 Hz", the dropdown box is also disabled, but it doesn't matter, after all if I enable this device the sound doesn't work.

[image]

Looking into the device administrator, the device appears twice as well:

[image]

Controller is up to date, according to the interface (both Headsets SE-MJ553BT Stereo and Headsets with microphone SE-MJ553BT Hands-Free use the same):

[image]

#### What have I tried?.

- Reboot computer.
- Repair device.
- Update drivers.
- Chat with Microsoft customer support.
- [RTFM](https://www.pioneerelectronics.com/ephox/StaticFiles/PUSA/Files/Home/SE-MJ553BT-Es-001.pdf).
- Google it!.

Under troubleshooting section on the manual, the manufacturer advises to "*Check if the Bluetooth connection is adjusted to use the A2DP profile*"; I don't know how to check this so I googled for it and found this question on the site:

- [Force bluetooth headphones to connect with A2DP profile on WIndows](https://superuser.com/questions/944720/force-bluetooth-headphones-to-connect-with-a2dp-profile-on-windows?newreg=8f84b7c81b5b428baa13421d961c2149)

But it doesn't help me since the dropdown menu doesn't show the same items:

[image]

Neither does the "Services" tab:

[image]

#### Thanks.

Thank you for reading this far, hope you can help me somehow. Have a nice day!