# Sony bluetooth headphones - poor sound quality

Tags: windows, audio, bluetooth, headphones

My Sony Sony WH-CH700N bluetooth headphones are no longer working properly when connected to a Windows 10 PC that they previously worked with. When connected, I see two options when clicking on the sound icon in the taskbar and clicking on the up arrow:

[image]

- Choosing Headset (WH-CH700N Hands-Free AG Audio) results in poor sound quality
- Choosing Headphones (WH-CH700N Stereo) results in no sound

A [Sony help page for the headphones](https://helpguide.sony.net/mdr/whch700n/v1/en/contents/TP0001613506.html) says

> If you have previously connected the headset to this Bluetooth device, only an HFP/HSP Bluetooth connection may be made when the headset is turned on. If this happens, use the Bluetooth device and make an A2DP Bluetooth connection.

Is that a possible factor?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Update: I had a similar issue with my Sony WF-1000XM4 earphones when I had Davinci Resolve open. My answer applies for it too.

---

I figured out the solution, helped by stumbling upon [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/944731/291776). This could apply to other bluetooth headphones too.

1. Open Settings

   - Windows 11: go to Settings > Bluetooth & devices > Devices, scroll down to "Related settings" and click on "More device and printer settings"
   - Windows 10: go to Settings > Devices, then on the right under "Related settings", click on "Devices and printers"
2. Right click on the headphones and click "Properties"

   [image]
3. Go to the "Services" tab and, in my case, untick "Hands free Telephony"

   [image]

I then had to turn off the bluetooth in Windows, then it on again and reconnect to the headphones. After that, the sound worked and was clear. I no longer got the "WH-CH700N Hands-Free AG Audio" option, only the "WH-CH700N Stereo" option

Comment: Thank you SO much for this one -- works with my c700n as well!